# Fix Google Chrome bug for my website CSS related

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Once again I'm making a website. This time I want to keep it clean. Everything works, even in Internet Explorer except for one thing in Google Chrome.
The menu appears under the dark menu bar in google chrome. Once you refresh it would be correctly positioned but for some reason it doesn't work on the first page load.

**On first page load**:
[image]

**after refresh**:
[image]

Weird...

HTML:

```
<div id="top_bar">
            <div class="engraved" id="logo"><span>Codiction</span></div>

            <div id="menu" class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current">Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul {
display: inline-block;
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-height: 29px;
height: 29px;
list-style-type:none; 
position: relative;
z-index: 110;
}

.menu {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
min-height: 29px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Thanks if you can fix this!

Comment: MAybe you have some CSS selectors in the wrong order, or something like that.

Comment: I would think it's google chrome's fault. Every other browser does not have this bug.

Comment: @user2342400 or every other browser has a bug and Google Chrome displays it right ;-)

Comment: For something to not work in Chrome as it should us pretty rare. (not fanboy talk) Do you have alink to the actual page?

Comment: The problem might not be with the code that you supplied. It might be else where on your site

Comment: http://beta.codiction.com/exp this is the page. The CSS is a modified extension xvn and I used PHP in it to build a few thousand empty lines.

Comment: I do admit that I am not familiar with positioning two divs next to eachother. It took me alot of trying and made the code a bit messy. My apologies.

Comment: It seems like to be a problem with the `position:absolute` of `.menu`.

Comment: @w4rumy Why does chrome display it correctly once you refresh the page? And how else would I be able to position two divs next to eachother (in my case: the logo and then the menu next to it)

Comment: @DiederikEEn Here is the entire CSS: http://pastebin.com/xjDQQj9y

Comment: @user2342400 try to give your LI a width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float` to place two divs next to each other. Try

```
.engraved { float:left; }
```

Comment: Do I remove the position:absolute; attributes from the other divs? EDIT: Nevermind I found it

Comment: Thanks alot, it seems to be working now! I added float:left to #logo and removed position:absolute from .menu